# startActivityForResult Deprecated in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to learn Google Sign In Authentication with Firebase in Kotlin but since the startActivityForResult Deprecated in Kotlin I'm having some troubles. Button can be clicked but it does not do anything. Here's what I've done so far :

*I only included the question's scope codes*

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.signInBtn.setOnClickListener {
       signIn()
    }
}
```

```
private fun signIn(){
       val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
       signInActivityResultLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
   }

private val signInActivityResultLauncher =
     registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
       if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
          Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }
}
```

Comment: I Think there is no wrong code. But if there is no intent action, You can try to check `Intent` is right by using debug or logcat. It may have problem the google(firebase) settings If `signInIntent ` is not working well.

Comment: @liveAnyway yeah it turned out my emulator device was not supported for Play Store, I changed my device and the problem solved. Like you said the code was fine. Thank you for your time and suggestion :)